# How to append mathjax code to a div

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I am experimenting with Mathjax. I want user to enter code in a textarea and want to append it to a div.

```
function getText(){
   var content=document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
   var math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("viewer")[0];
   MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Text",math,content])

}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gourab/C5G55/) is the fiddle. I couldn't understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine: [updatedFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5G55/1/), you need to select `No wrap - in <body>` from the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

more detailed version with comments
token from official site
http://jsfiddle.net/C5G55/3/ `.`